# How can i add expressions to handlebars partials parameters

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, expression, partials

How can i add expressions to partials parameters? I want to do something like that:

```
{{> myPartial greeting=(i18n.greeting + "my text") }}
```

Comment: You will need a helper to do the string concatenation.

Comment: I am trying to find out how i can create a helper. I created the helper function i18n. It works for {{i18n 'greeting'}} but it doesn't work inside a partial: {{> myPartial greeting="(i18n 'greeting')" }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Handlebars documentation has a [section on subexpressions](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#subexpressions). It tells us that the way to pass the results of inner helper as the argument to outer helpers is done as follows:

```
{{> myPartial greeting=(i18n 'greeting') }}
```

However, it looks from your question that you might be trying to concatenate some string values into a single `greeting` parameter for your partial. If this is the case, you will need to create (or import) a helper that will concatenate strings for you and then apply this helper as another subexpression. The result would look like the following:

```
{{> myPartial greeting=(concat (i18n greeting) 'my text') }}
```

The required helper could be done as follows:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('concat', function () {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0, -1).join('');
});
```

Comment: Thanks! i had an error in my subespression, i wrote it this way {{> myPartial greeting=("i18n greeting") }} and thought subexpressions wont work in parameters.

Answer (score 0):

That depends in how your configure the server options with nodeJS
I configured the functions in res.locals (Version Express Over 4.0) with a '__' expression so in the example look like this

***{{> myPartial greeting=(i18n 'greeting')}}***

Your JSON file in locales should have this key and it'd be magic...

By the way to concat your key with any string should be this way

***{{> myPartial greeting=(i18n 'Hello %s', 'Marcus')}}***

I hope you find this useful..